# How to select parent whose name equals child name

Tags: json, select, jq

I thought this would be simple, but I'm stumped. How can I select the parent `hostvars` entry for each child `activedirectory_devops.hosts` entry? If this were SQL, I'd try writing a `join`.

```
    {
        "_meta": {
            "hostvars": {
                "foo_423d1fe9-d964-d45e-ec69-2565589deae6": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.0.1",
                "config.cpuHotAddEnabled": true,
                "config.cpuHotRemoveEnabled": false,
                "config.hardware.numCPU": 4,
                "config.instanceUuid": "503d1a90-8b07-4b33-2648-5d1f9330e5f7",
                "config.name": "devops-dal13-bc1",
                "config.template": false,
                "guest.guestId": "windows9Server64Guest",
                "guest.guestState": "running",
                "guest.hostName": "foo.company.com",
                "guest.ipAddress": "192.168.0.1",
                "inventory_dir": "/ansible/inventories",
                "inventory_file": "/ansible/inventories/vcsa2.vmware.yml",
                "name": "foo",
                "runtime.maxMemoryUsage": 16384
            },
,
                "bar_420b8b36-fffe-6f29-3e32-0ce9aa0d0ad3": {
                    "config.cpuHotAddEnabled": false,
                    "config.cpuHotRemoveEnabled": false,

...
            }
        }
    },
    "activedirectory_devops": {
        "hosts": [
            "foo_423d1fe9-d964-d45e-ec69-2565589deae6",
            "bar_420b8b36-fffe-6f29-3e32-0ce9aa0d0ad3"
        ]
    },
```

My incomplete attempt:

```
jq '. as $parent | .activedirectory_devops.hosts as $children | .'
```

Comment: Please post a valid JSON sample.  It should be concise and to-the-point in accordance with the [tag:mcve] guideline. Also, don't forget to show the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I select the parent hostvars entry for each child activedirectory_devops.hosts entry?

The following jq query does exactly that:

```
.activedirectory_devops.hosts[] as $host
| ._meta.hostvars[$host]
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that `[]` were valid accessors for objects. I thought they could only be used for arrays. Does that explain why `._meta.hostvars.$host` fails with `syntax error, unexpected '$'`?

Comment: @mellow-yellow - `$` is regarded as a special character that cannot be used in jq identifiers; this means that according to the current rules, `.$foo` is invalid, but I don't see why the jq parser couldn't be enhanced to allow it as an abbreviation of `.[$foo]`